# old \def definitions linger

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax

It's possible to use `\def`, and it usually works. However, there's a problem in that the definitions stick around and there seems to be no way to get rid of them short of reloading the page. This might not be so bad if it weren't for the fact that it messes up standard commands whose names appear temporarily while a custom command name is being typed.

For instance, say I have `\int_{-\pi}^\pi` and I realize I'll be writing lots of these integrals, so I enclose it in braces and type `\def\intp` in front of it. Before I type the final 'p', the result is `\def\int{\int_{-\pi}^\pi}`. This redefines `\int` (in this case to something self-referential that causes an error), and that definition doesn't get cleared when I type the final 'p'. (This happens no matter how fast I type.) From then on, trying to use `\int` causes an error, even after deleting the entire definition, and the only way to get it to work again seems to be to reload the page.

Comment: Hmmm. Is this an SE bug or a [MathJax](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues) one?

Comment: @cardinal: Sounds like either a MathJax bug, or a MathJax "feature" that we should turn off.

Comment: This is probably a silly suggestion, but if this is due to insta-parsing...Does it help, if you **paste** 'intp' to the correct place as opposed to **type** it?

Comment: @Jyrki: Yes, there are various workarounds -- you can also type the entire definition and then add the `\def` in front of it.

Comment: Can someone confirm whether this is still an issue?

Comment: @Oded It is; I [tested it now](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MMSu0.png).  This [answer by Davide Cervone](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4140/) describes how MathJax scoping `begingroup... endgroup` can be used to deal with leaking definitions, but implementing it would require some changes to SE code.

Comment: Geoff Dalgas updated this to say [tag:status-completed], but didn't say why.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I took a quick look at how macro definitions are implemented in MathJax, and from what I can tell, this is a MathJax bug, or rather, a missing feature.  In fact, there are two features that would make the way we use MathJax work better:

- Some way to reset TeX macro definitions (and ideally any other mutable state) back to its previous state after a `Typeset` call.  It might be possible to hack this locally by poking into MathJax internals (pull a copy of the definitions from the [TeX InputJax](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/blob/master/unpacked/jax/input/TeX/jax.js) before calling `Typeset` and stick it back afterwards), but it would be much better to have an officially supported way to do this.
- Some way to tell MathJax to *automatically* reset macro definitions after processing the content of appropriately marked HTML elements on the page.  That way, we could for example mark each post on a page so that macro definitions wouldn't leak between them.  This should also take care of the preview issues, assuming that the preview container was thus marked.

Anyone else feel like reporting these to the MathJax folks, or shall I?

Comment: You seem to have already done most of the work. My opinion is that you should report your findings.

Comment: Reported: [Feature request: limit scope of TeX macro definitions (issue #186)](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/186).

Comment: @Ilmari: Thanks for that!

Comment: This has [come up again](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4130/the-scope-of-newcommand-is-the-entire-page).  Note that MathJax 2.0 includes code that can be used to solve this issue on SE.