# The scope of \newcommand is the entire page

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax, newcommand

LaTeX on this site supports `\newcommand` and `\renewcommand`.  This is very nice, but I noticed that the scope of these definitions is the entire rest of the page.  That's consistent with how LaTeX behaves, but it could be undesirable on this site where the page contains posts by different people: one person's `\newcommand` affects everyone who posts below them.

To illustrate the problem, in this question I am including

> `\renewcommand{\sin}{\cos}`

$\renewcommand{\sin}{\cos}$Now anyone who uses `\sin` in an answer or a comment will get $\cos$ instead.

(I considered exploiting this when asking some simple trig question on main and then watching the confusion, but decided not to be evil.)

It would be good if the scope of `\newcommand` and friends could be limited to the current question/answer/comment, but I don't know whether this is possible.

Comment: Let's try an example in a comment: $\sin \pi = 0$.  Indeed, it makes me look like a fool.

Comment: This is a known issue.

Comment: This is known, but this can be rather easily remedied: You can edit the malicious post; you can \renewcommand; and you can flag for moderator with a comment explaining what is happening. Perhaps we should institute a norm that whenever someone is intentionally breaking $\LaTeX$ the post will be flagged for moderator attention (even after correcting) and the moderators will warn the user, since breaking math display on a mathematical site is a first-degree level of trolling!

Comment: I made things worse! :-D $\renewcommand{\cos}{\sum}\renewcommand{\sum}{\stackrel{\circ\cdot\circ}{\Huge \smile}}\renewcommand{\pi}{\text{BAM! You have been trolled!}}$

Comment: Maybe this is a dumb question, but why *should* the site allow `\renewcommand`? I can understand `\DeclareMathOperator` and `\newcommand` which seem much less dangerous because clashes are rather unlikely, but I can't think of a really good use of `\renewcommand`.

Comment: Someone could want to copy over latex code that they already have with their custom commands.

Comment: What if a second `\newcommand` or `\renewcommand` was in the comments? $$\renewcommand{\sin}{\left.{{\unicode{x263A}}\atop{\unicode{x263A}}}\right)}$$

Comment: @J.M.: As my previous comment shows, it breaks things just as well. In which case flagging for a moderator attention is needed. $\renewcommand{sin}{\text{Beer is Good!}}$

Comment: I [commented about that here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/poll-for-mathjax-macros-that-should-be-automatically-loaded#comment13972_3718) some time ago. Related question: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/poll-for-mathjax-macros-that-should-be-automatically-loaded

Comment: @t.b. I would not prohibit them. I personally prefer `\geqslant` ($\geqslant$) over `geq` ($\geq$) and thus write `\let\geq\geqslant` in the beginning of my posts. (I don't want to write `\geqslant` every time.) Same with `\phi` ($\phi$) and `\varphi` ($\varphi$).

Comment: I found that in order to include such definitions, they have to be put between dollar signs so that MathJax can see them. This leads to a space being included, which is the rendering of this empty equation. Is there a way to suppress this space?

Comment: @A.Donda Put it in the same equation as the first usage (or any other existing MathJax), rather than making the definition stand on its own, i.e. `$\DeclareMathOperator{\ran}{ran}\ran f=\emptyset$` to get $\DeclareMathOperator{\ran}{ran}\ran f=\emptyset$.

Comment: How dastardly evil!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [old \def definitions linger](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3394/old-def-definitions-linger)

Comment: Testing: $\sin \pi=0$

Comment: @A.Donda, the empty space is not the result of rendering the empty equation (which has empty result), but of any following space.  For example, `$\def\a{a}$ \a` results in a space, but `$\def\a{a}$\a` doesn't.

Comment: $\sin\pi=0$....

Comment: As @iBug's comment indicates, [SE software changes](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4103/problem-with-posts-and-comments-relying-on-macros-defined-elsewhere) have removed this problem, sorta kinda, in the sense that new posts, or newly edited ones, are now isolated from their surrounding environments.

Answer (score 29):

It pains me to break this thread by fixing the issue, but here we are. :)

We are now inserting `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` directives into post and comment bodies, so all command definitions should be scoped to individual posts.

For now, I'm only enabling this on Math (and here on meta), but barring any issues this change will go live on all MathJax-enabled sites next week.

Comment: It seems that the issue isn't completely fixed.  See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29702/18398

Comment: To add a bit more to detail to @Joel's comment: a newcommand in titles can still cause issues. This is especially a problem when a title containing a newcommand appears in "linked" and "related." This can create rather confusing situations.

Comment: It's still broken if you do $\endgroup \renewcommand{\sin}{\cos} \begingroup$ \endgroup \renewcommand{\sin}{\cos} \begingroup. As you can see, it broke the post below.

Comment: @qbt937 Yeah... Although honestly, that isn't something that would come up naturally. The only way this'd happen is from someone *trying* to mess with the page and I'm okay with leaving that up to being edited out and the user potentially being suspended if they keep at it.

Comment: Thanks for making the change. How are you faring with this, is anything rolled out over the other sites already? Or are there still issues to be fixed / high prio tasks taking precedence? Cheers, Maarten, mod at [cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com). Or should we create a feature request to obtain it?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes It's live on every SE site that has Mathjax enabled. You don't need to do anything special.

Comment: Of course, now some of comments and answers are not rendered correctly - if the OP used macro defined in the question. (And, of course, at that time they were rendered fine.) But probably there is not too many of them and some of them might eventually get edited. More on this [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/88939/2019/1/29) and in  A [recent post by quid](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29852/what-to-do-about-comments-with-broken-mathjax) is somewhat related. And there was [a short discussion on MathOveverflow Meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4103).

Comment: @AdamLear I have posted a [follow-up question concerning macros in titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30386) - asking both whether titles should be inside begingroup...endgroup too and to which extent defining macros in the titles should be discouraged.

Answer (score 24):

As Mariano points out, this has been [reported before](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3394/old-def-definitions-linger).  Because of that conversation, MathJax v2.0 includes an extension (the [begingroup](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#begingroup) extension) that would allow you to isolate the effects of `\def`, `\newcommand`, etc. to a single question, answer, or comment, but it would require changes to the SE code to force that to be used.

The changes would be to include `begingroup.js` in the TeX extensions array for the site's configuration, and outputing a `$\begingroup$` at the beginning of each questions/answer/comment and an `$\endgroup$` at the end.  (These might want to be enclosed in a hidden `<div>` or some other tag so that they don't introduce any unwanted space.)  The preview code would also have to be modified to include these, but that would need to be a bit more sophisticated, since the typesetting can be canceled in the middle (by new characters being typed) so the final `\endgroup` would need to be handled separately in that case.  I would be happy to work that out if the powers-that-be wanted to coordinate efforts on that.

**Edit**:  Asaf asks whether you can do anything like this "by hand".  I had considered telling you about the `\require{}` command that will load extensions that haven't been included in the configuration, but I didn't.  That's because the current preview code will not work well with the `begingroup` extension.  If you include a `$\begingroup$` in your post, but haven't yet typed the `$\endgroup$`, then each character you type will cause the post to be reprocessed, and each reprocessing will cause a new `\begingroup` to be performed without a corresponding `\endgroup`.  This will use up memory that will not be freed (until you go to another page), and can slow MathJax down.

Similarly, if you have a long post, then even if you *do* have matching `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` tags, if you type fast, each letter will cancel MathJax in the middle of what it is doing, and so MathJax may be canceled after processing the `\begingroup` but before the `\endgroup`.  Again, you can use up memory.

This is what I meant when I said that the preview code would need to be modified to take that into account.

While it is technically possible to use the `begingroup` extension by hand, you would have to be careful about how you do it.  On the plus side, it only affects you when you are editing (or someone else who is editing your work), so perhaps you would be willing to put up with the difficulties.

In any case, your example doesn't really show how it would work, since `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` don't protect you from definitions from outside your answer; they protect others from definitions in *your* answer.  So to see it really work, you would need to use something like

```
$$
  \require{begingroup}
  \begingroup
\renewcommand{\tan}{\operatorname{grey}}
\tan\theta
  \endgroup
  \ne
  \tan\phi
$$
```

to get

$$
\require{begingroup}
\begingroup
  \renewcommand{\tan}{\operatorname{grey}}
  \tan\theta
\endgroup
\ne
\tan\phi
$$

This works, but if you don't get the balancing of begin and end groups properly during the editing process, you can be left with a lot of open begin groups, that contain local definitions that don't go away (until you reload the page).

Comment: Is this workaround applicable "by hand"? (Testing: $\begingroup\sin\neq\cos\endgroup$)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I added material to my original answer about that.

Comment: Yes, I saw. Thank you. Do note that the main problem which Nate pointed is that vandals can post a malicious code and "ruin" the answer.

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  That is why I said it would take changes to the SE code to do this properly.  I thought you were asking about using \begingroup and \endroup yourself (to isolate your local macros so they don't interfere with others).  Perhaps I misunderstood.  I do not see a way to prevent others from making definitions without changes to SE code.

Comment: I was hoping that there would be a way to locally reset inside an answer.

Comment: I suppose if the questioner added `$\require{begingroup}\begingroup$` at the bottom of the question, you could use `$\endgroup\begingroup$` at the top *and* bottom of your answer or isolate your response from the effects of others (and localize your changes to your answer as well).  But this takes cooperation of the questioner, and it also has all the preview problems that I mentioned.

Comment: That is effectively what I am suggesting that the SE code does between *each* question/answer/comment, but you could do it by hand for your answer provided there was an initial \begingroup in the question.

Comment: Of course that would still only prevent accidental macro leaking, not malicious leaking. For one, the begingroup extension also provides `\gdef`, which works around `\begingroup`/`endgroup`. Moreover, even without `\gdef`, a malicious poster could simply use`\endgroup\renewcommand{\sin}{\cos}\begingroup` to make his definition intentionally leaking. So if the goal is to prevent malicious behaviour, it has to use a mechanism which isn't accessible to users.

Comment: Your point is well taken, but I think it could be handled as follows:  make a new macro `\reset` that does the action of `\endgroup\begingroup` (easily done), and remove the `\begingroup`, `\endgroup`, `\gdef`, and `\global` macros.  Use `$\reset$` between questions/answers/posts, and rather than call MathJax's typeset by itself, first queue the `\begingroup` function directly, then the typeset then the `\endgroup` function.  While the user could still call `\reset` in her message, it would not provide a means of entering global definitions.

Comment: @DavideCervone: If you make `\reset` completely reset the MathJax engine (i.e. remove even macros defined globally), there's no need to remove the macros from the begingroup extension. But you're right, `\reset` being available to users would not be harmful.

Comment: @Davide: I added a fix for this issue into [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch), but it's kind of crude: I'm basically just injecting the equivalent of `$\endgroup$ $\begingroup$` at the beginning of each post and comment. It's working, but if you'd have any suggestions on how to do it more cleanly / elegantly, please do tell. The current code I have is [here](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/blob/5cabb164ef49a4cdaac2d044d0867c4a61bc66bd/SOUP.user.js#L156) (look for `mathJaxSetup`).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, what you have looks good except for two things:  (1) you don't need to have two separate expressions, you could just do `$\endroup\begingroup$`, and (2), it is possible for a user to redefine `\endgroup` or `\begingroup` within their post.  Preventing that would require overriding part of MathJax's code for defining macros (but it could be done).  Also, make sure you first post only starts with `$\begingroup$` with no leading `\endgroup`, and your last one should only have `$\endgroup$`.

Comment: @DavideCervone: The reason I'm using two separate expressions is precisely so that if `\endgroup` fails (because the stack is already empty), the following `\begingroup` will still run. While I could omit the first `\endgroup` and the last `\begingroup` on the page as you suggest, having new posts or other content loaded via AJAX could still cause subsequent typeset passes to start with an unbalanced `\endgroup`, so I have to tolerate that possibility. What I'd really _like_ to do is implement your / celtschk's `\reset` idea above, but I don't know enough about MathJax internals to see how.

Comment: @DavideCervone: OK, I did figure out [how to do it](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/blob/7a7b1d0a1f9c63bcebabf666d8629a82126e3428/SOUP.user.js#L160) by monkey-patching parts of the begingroup extension. It's a bit complicated, and likely to break if the extension ever gets rewritten, but otherwise it works very nicely.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, actually, I quite like it over all.  Would you might if I incorporate something similar into the begingroup extension directly?  You use an approach I hadn't thought of, and I think it works nicely (as you point out).  BTW, there are a couple of other things that could be added to SOUP that I might suggest, but this is not the right pace for that.  Where is best to discuss such things?

Comment: @DavideCervone: Please do, if you like. I should really add an explicit licensing note to SOUP, but feel free to consider it [CC-Zero](http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/).  As for discussing SOUP, I guess the [StackApps page](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) would do, or we could even try [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27/stack-apps), although I've never really managed to get into the habit of using it much.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, thanks.  I'm opening an feature request on the MathJax site to make sure I remember to do it at the next opportunity.  I will use the StackApps page for additional suggestions.

Comment: Does begin/endgroup cost much in terms of efficiency? I worry that with Chrome crashing frequently, if these cause a lot of computation, it may worsen things with Chrome. Is there yet any workaround for the Chrome crashes? I still lose work frequently because of this. I think I'll have to give up using Chrome with Mathjax. It's truly unfortunate that Mathjax is highly incompatible with the best browser.

Comment: @BillDubuque, in terms of efficiency, there would be an extra file loaded (the begingroup extension), and there is a slight cost to macro lookups for each level of nesting.  You would not notice the difference for the one level of nesting that Ilmari's SOUP script applies.  As for Chrome, since I am unable to reproduce the issue that you have having, it is not something that I can really address.  My own experience is that Chrome since version 18 has become much less stable and much less reliable.  But I'm not really interested in starting a browser war.

Comment: @Davide Thanks, that's useful to know. Do you mean that you find Chrome more unstable in general, or only with MathJax? Almost all of my Chrome crashes are in MathJax. Rarely does it crash elsewhere (except when I'm near out of memory). Perhaps Chrome doesn't gracefully handle running out of some kind of resource, and MathJax triggers that more frequently than other apps?

Comment: More unstable in general.  Our discussions in [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4037/showstopper-bug-msemathjax-unusable-for-6-months-with-chrome) certainly discuss the issue of running out of memory, and so on.  At that time, I had posted a user script that I thought might address the issue, and asked you to try it out.  You said you would, but I don't see any response to that (and don't recall one).  I'm not sure if the user script still applies (the SE code may well have changed since then).

Comment: @PeterTaylor, I have updated the documentation link.  Thanks for pointing out the bit-rot.

Comment: @Davide Was the preview code also modified to prevent said inefficiencies after the SE change mentioned in Adam's answer?  Is there any negative impact of these recent grouping changes?

Comment: @BillDubuque, not to my knowledge, but I'm not involved in maintaining the preview code.  But I'm not sure which inefficiencies you are referring to.  The one I mention in my answer was because the `\begingroup` was part of the answer itself in my example above.  I don't believe that is the case with the code that has been added to SE.

Answer (score 10):

This answer will serve as a demonstration:

$$\sin \pi = 0$$

What I typed was true (edit or view source), but what you see is false.

Comment: When $\sin$ is $\sin$ and $\cos$ is $\sin$! Pythagoras rolls over in his unmarked grave.

Answer (score 10):

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$As [discussed in the comments](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/48947) to Davide Cervone's answer, I have added a client-side fix to this bug to version 1.2. of the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch).

The fix works by injecting a special hidden TeX command (currently named `\resetstack`) at the beggining of each post, comment, snippet (as shown e.g. on the front page) or question/answer link (as in the sidebar), which resets the TeX InputJax macro definitions to their default values.

The [implementation](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/blob/2c7208a9ff27577bf250e18c1cac4b56b652a293/SOUP.user.js#L160) is currently a bit complicated, but hopefully it can be simplified later, if some of the needed code is incorporated directly into MathJax as Davide suggests in the comments.

### Some important notes about the fix:

Since SOUP is a client-side user script, installing it will fix the bug for you, *but not for others.*  In particular, any definitions made in *your* posts will still leak to other posts when viewed by users who don't have SOUP installed (which, alas, means most of them).

I therefore *strongly* recommend that, if you use `\def`, `\(re)newcommand` or other such features in your posts, you should always prefix them with:

```
$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$
```

and end them with:

```
$\endgroup$
```

to keep your definitions from leaking into other posts.  (Note that using SOUP should eliminate any memory leak issues due to unclosed `\begingroup` tags while composing a post, since SOUP will reset the definition stack whenever the preview pane is re-typeset.)

You should also avoid redefining symbols in question titles, or *anywhere near the top of your posts* where the definitions would be likely to show up on the front page or in search results.  (Alas, there's currently no 100% reliable way to prevent that from happening, except by not redefining TeX commands at all.)

Because of these issues, `\def` and friends are still best used sparingly, and *only* for things that would be unlikely to conflict with notation in other posts.  For example, `\newcommand{\foo}{\operatorname{foo}}` is probably fine, but `\newcommand{\sin}{\cos}` is not.

Also note that, even with SOUP, definitions imported from extensions via `\require` will still leak into other posts.  This is pretty much impossible to avoid without breaking some extensions badly, and should basically be considered as being by design.$\endgroup$

---

**Edit:** Turns out that my original implementation of this fix suffered from a race condition that made it work on Firefox only occasionally.  This should be fixed in v1.2.1 that I just released; anyone using it is strongly advised to [upgrade](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/raw/master/SOUP.user.js).

(Also, the upcoming v1.4 release of SOUP will have more MathJax scoping fixes, including one for `\label`s, again based on a suggestion by Davide Cervone.  Those still need some more testing before release, though.)

Comment: Is it possible that SOUP could implement some sort of autosave feature to prevent loss of work due to frequent Chrome + MathJax crashes? The problem is so severe that I don't even dare to use MathJax with Chrome any more (except for trivial answers), having already lost countless hours of work due to such crashes.

Comment: @Bill: The SE editor [is already supposed to autosave posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1177), although only every 45 seconds. Of course, the _real_ problem here is MathJax crashing Chrome, which presumably counts as a bug in both MathJax and Chrome. FWIW, I suspect things may have improved somewhat -- I use both Firefox and Chrome, and do recall experiencing poor rendering and slowdowns during editing (if not outright crashes) on the latter in the past, but not so much recently (except on the Android version of Chrome, which does get bogged down by lots of math).

Comment: Alas, the SE "autosave" feature is a kludge that works only rarely to recover from Chrome crashes. Any heavy use of MathJax + Chrome causes frequent Chrome crashses, making MathJax essentially unusable on Chrome. It's been this way for many years now. If it cannot be fixed, it would be *really, really* great to have some workaround, if that is not too much trouble to implement. This is by far the worst software problem I've encountered in a few decades of heavy software use. It's a shame that it has gone on this long. You can see many complaints about it in old meta posts.

Comment: I agree. I can't really fix it without knowing _why_ it happens, though, and I don't think anyone's really figured that out yet. (If someone has, please do tell me.)

Comment: I highly doubt it will ever happen. David claims it is a bug in Chrome tckled by MathJax. So the only hope is a workaround. Surely it must be *very easy* to implement a halfway decent autosave feature in SOUP, right? This would be the best thing since sliced bread. It would save many Chrome users countless hours of lost work.

Comment: It _might_ be possible using LocalStorage, although if Chrome crashes badly enough, that might not be perfectly safe either. I've never actually used LocalStorage before, but I could take a look into it. I'd also have to find some way to keep it from fighting with the SE builtin autosave feature, though.

Comment: Thanks! Even something more primitive such as saving to the clipboard would be helpful. The goal is to *guarantee* that one will not lose much work even if the browser crashes (which is very far from true for the SE draft saving feature)

Comment: Javascript doesn't have access to the clipboard (for security reasons), so that is not likely to be a solution.  There are some Flash-based kludges, but in general, browsers prevent javascript frmo modifying the clipboard.

Answer (score -1):

#### Fun fact:

in addition to

```
\newcommand{\sin}{\cos}
```

you can also include

```
\newcommand{\cos}{\sin}
```

and flat-out break all the code that uses those commands. Or, if you felt inclined to be evil, you could e.g. do a cyclic redefinition of the entire Greek alphabet, or something. Not that you *should*, of course.

Comment: How does this contribute to the discussion?

Comment: It illustrates how bad this bug is

Comment: In case it is not obvious, this pair of definitions will *not* swap the roles of `\sin` and `\cos`. Rather, it will make both macros unusable, as they are now defined by mutual recursion that never comes to an end, leading to a “MathJax maximum macro substitution count exceeded” error.