# A possible bug regarding MathJax, previews, and the arctangent/tangent functions?

Tags: bug, mathjax, titles, newcommand

For context, I was making a tweak to GReyes' answer on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3090234/what-is-the-arctan-of-12-5), just cleaning up some formatting with the trigonometric functions. Specifically, I was turning `arctan` to `\arctan` and `tan` to `\tan` in the MathJax code.

Below is the code in the post and the preview that resulted (blue boxes highlighting the relevant bits):

---

[image: The bug]

---

In short, the functions in the preview become sine/arcsine functions instead of tangent/arctangent.

On playing around, I noticed this does not happen if I instead put `\cos` or `\arccos`, or `\sec`, `\csc`, or `\cot`. Only `\tan` and `\arctan` would render as sine and arcsine.

What's more intriguing - and confusing! - is that this glitch seems localized only to this question. Playing around on other answers (obviously not saving my edits), I can't reproduce the effects of the glitch. But, another answer to that same question has the tangent/arctangent functions rendering as intended - though on opening it up to edit it, the same glitch arises without me so much as changing a letter!)

---

[image: The glitch again!]

---

Yet other questions that involve tangent/arctangent functions don't seem to be affected: [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3077882/cant-figure-out-how-sin-left-tan-1x-right-fracx-sqrt-x21) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3084351/how-to-solve-inverse-trig-equations-like-sinarctan-2) for example.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this glitch? I feel like it might just be something on my end, but I honestly don't know.

I admit that I don't know MathJax/LaTeX particularly well - I'm terrible at programming and coding in general, and only know what I do of these from experience and seeing other posts - so maybe there's something dumb I'm overlooking. In which case if this is just a waste of time, sorry.

Comment: The answer shows that this was caused by `\newcommand` in a title of a question. I will just add link to discussion about another problem which might be caused by use of newcommand in titles: [MathJax rendering in preview but not in actual post?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29407) (See the comments in that question.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A linked question contained some malicious code in the title. I've removed it.

[image]

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4130/the-scope-of-newcommand-is-the-entire-page effectively includes instructions on how to cause this bug. I can't help wondering if it's wise to keep them (and this) around.

Comment: @timtfj As the [most recent answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4130#29621) in the question you linked explains, this has been already resolved for posts and comments. Probably some kind of similar fix can be used for titles - after that newcommand and similar commands should be "safe". (In fact, I did not notice this recent change - it was [pointed out to me by quid](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48737413#48737413) in our recent [conversation in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64952/conversation/problem-with-newcommand-in-titles) about this problem.)

Comment: This asker apparently also included the same malicious code in their [one other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/885533/revisions). I have a feeling that the purpose of these posts was just to "trick" people trying to answer the question. A real comedian...

Answer (score 6):

One of the links from Greyes' question is: [Simple trig problem-](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/885521/renewcommand-tan-sin-renewcommand-arctan-arcsinsimple-trig-problem) whose URL is actually
math.stackexchange.com/questions/885521/renewcommand-tan-sin-renewcommand-arctan-arcsinsimple-trig-problem
which looks suspicious but my HTML skills are limited so this might be a red herring.