# Syntax to use \newcommand in a post

Tags: support, mathjax

What is the syntax to use `\newcommand` in a post?
I tried

> \$\newcommand{\foo}{1+1}\$

But this leave a blank line.
Also, for severals `\newcommand`

> \$\$
>   \newcomand{\foo}{1+1}
>   \newcomand{\bar}{2+2}
>   \$\$

also leaves blank lines in the post

Comment: Related (mainly to the points raised by robjohn's answer): [The scope of \newcommand is the entire page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4130).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually use `\newcommand` at the end of the first paragraph, which is usually introductory which does not contain much LaTeX. You can use several `\newcommand` sequentially within a single `$` environment and it works fine.$\newcommand{\example}{\mathsf{For\space example\space as\space in\space this\space post}}$

$$\example$$

Comment: I'm glad your answer was accepted. If mine were accepted, it would show first and not be affected by your `\newcommand`.

Comment: @robjohn: In the case your were accepted it would have made another point clear, but let me rain on your answer from above and say... $\renewcommand{\example}{\mathsf{This\space is\space SPARTA}!}$

Answer (score 3):

Beware the side-effects of using `\newcommand` in a post or in chat. As MathJax is currently implemented, it affects all the subsequent posts on the page; e.g.
$$
\example
$$
This might make sort dependent rendering of answers.

Comment: Not to mention an overrun by marauders!$$\sin(x)=\newcommand{\sin}{\text{TROLL'd!}}\sin(x)$$

Comment: The `edit` button is not clickable for me. Is there another way to look at the internal of your post? I have the same problem with Asaf post, but there I could click on `edited 1 hout ago`.

Comment: @NicolasEssis-Breton: right-click on the rendered MathJax and a contextual menu should pop up. Choose "Show Math As > TeX Commands" and you should see `\example`.

Comment: @NicolasEssis-Breton: you can try [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/posts/8383/edit), but that might not work until you have 2K rep. Being on a different page, the `\example` command is not defined, so it is left unrendered in red.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$

Comment: The link you gave didn't work, but this [one](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/posts/8383/revisions) do.

Comment: @NicolasEssis-Breton: the link I gave must need 2K to work. Did you fabricate yours by substituting the ID of my answer into the link for Asaf's revisions?

Comment: Yes, that's what I did.

Comment: [Unfortunately](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26131/163), [this bug](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3394/163) is fixed now

Comment: ...whoops, actually it isn't fixed unless you install the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486)

Comment: Currently `\newcommand` should behave correctly again, and be particular to a specific post, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I will add to the previous comment that the change which limits scope of the macro to a single post (single comment) was announced in January 2019 as [on this meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4130/the-scope-of-newcommand-is-the-entire-page/29621#29621). This change is also mentioned in this list: [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange (2019)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/322016#322016).