# How to define string remap in MathJax

Tags: support, mathjax, newcommand

For example if there is a lot of $R^2$ and $C^2$ in a post, how to map the plain text R2 to $R^2$ only in this post like:

```
(start of define block mark)
define R2 $R^2$
define C2 $C^2$
(end of define block mark)
```

LaTeX commands is still too complex to reference again and again.

Comment: You can't do that. But you can do it with a backslash.

Comment: A related older post: [Syntax to use \newcommand in a post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8381),

Answer (score 6):

You can define macros in MathJax. As far as I can tell, you cannot use numbers in macro names. For example, this defines a macro called `\Rsq` which then types $\newcommand{\Rsq}{\mathbb R^2}\Rsq$.

```
$\newcommand{\Rsq}{\mathbb R^2}$ $\Rsq$
```

Macros can also use parameters. For example, the macro define below can be used as $\newcommand{\Map}[3]{{#1}\colon{#2}\to{#3}}$ `\Map fXY` to get $\Map fXY$ or `\Map\phi{[0,1]}{[0,1]}` $\Map\phi{[0,1]}{[0,1]}$.

```
$\newcommand{\Map}[3]{{#1}\colon{#2}\to{#3}}$
```

Other commands which can be used to define some "shortcut" are `\renewcommand`, `\DeclareMathOperator`, `\def` and `\let`. You can find many examples on the main site, if you search for [\newcommand](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Cnewcommand), [\renewcommand](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Crenewcommand), [\DeclareMathOperator](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5CDeclareMathOperator). It might be easier to find [examples of \def](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1104158/posts-containing-the-given-text-with-link-to-revisions?num=100&text=%5Cdef) and [examples of \let](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1104158/posts-containing-the-given-text-with-link-to-revisions?num=100&text=%5Clet) using [SEDE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info), since the built-in search might return some false positives.

It is recommended to avoid [using macros in the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-rm-latex-in-question-titles/9780#9780). If you define a macro, it will be available [within the post where you defined it](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4130/the-scope-of-newcommand-is-the-entire-page/29621#29621).

Syntax is basically the same as in LaTeX, you can find some basics in various places. For example, [TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-whatmacros), [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/How%20TeX%20macros%20actually%20work:%20Part%204), [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros)