# MathJax no longer respects `\newcommand` definitions from questions in other posts

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, mathjax, newcommand

In [a question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/337971/163) I used e.g. `$\newcommand{curl}{\operatorname{curl}}$` to define `$\curl$` being rendered as $\newcommand{curl}{\operatorname{curl}}\curl$. Back when I posted the question, answers and comments to that question where also capable of using the thus declared command. But now, using `$\curl$` elsewhere results in a red $\color{red}{\backslash\text{curl}}$.

I realize this [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) is actually the opposite of the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [old \def definitions linger](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3394/163), which states some very valid why `\newcommand` should usually *not* be global, so this request will probably be [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) or [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). Therefore this [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion):

> What is the proper way to provide mathjax `\newcommand`s that might help answerers and commenters in typesetting their response?

Should they simply have to copy-paste the definition which might become outdated due to a fix (e.g. in spacing)? Especially comments will suffer from this due to the character limit. Should we [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) an option to accept global `\newcommand`s or something else? A simple `$\usefrom{postid}{commandname}$`, e.g. `$\usefrom{337971}{curl}$` could also work, though that'd probably be a hassle to implement...

Comment: I suppose you mean the `\curl`s in [your answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/341812) and [this comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337971/can-the-curl-operator-be-generalized-to-non-3d#comment728439_337971). I currently see them rendered as one would expect ([image of post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6ehZ.png), [image of comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5ZBt.png)), and see no local definitions in either.

Comment: Are you perchance using Ilmari Karonen's [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch (SOUP)](http://stackapps.com/q/4486), which includes a client-side "fix" to the global definitions bug? (See [this meta.math post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4130).)

Comment: @arjafi Oh, I _do_. Never noticed that "fix" before. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's caused by the Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch

Comment: You can just delete your question...

Comment: Well, I don't think it should be closed or deleted. I believe this question might be helpful for other people.

Comment: Tobias Kienzler and @arjafi: I agree with Surb's comment that it is possible that this question could be useful for other users and it is better to keep it here. In my opinion a better option than closing would be expanding arjafi's comment to an an answer. (In that way when somebody faces the same problem and finds this post, the information will be displayed more prominently.)